# ORA-14287 Rebuilding a composite partitioned index on new tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Trying to move composite index partitions from tablespace A to tablespace B.
First I have moved all subpartitions successfully using DDL

```
ALTER INDEX idx1 REBUILD SUBPARTITION "0001234567889_1" TABLESPACE tablespace1 ONLINE PARALLEL;
```

dba_ind_subpartitions is now empty on originating tablespace. However indexes in dba_ind_partitions are still pointing to old tablespace. How do i change the tablespace of composite partitioned index?

I have tried rebuilding the indexes unsuccessfull:

```
SQL> ALTER INDEX idx1 REBUILD PARTITION "0001234567" TABLESPACE tablesspace1 ONLINE PARALLEL
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14287: cannot REBUILD a partition of a composite partitioned index
```

**EDIT**:
Is it no possible to rebuild the indexes? Do i need to drop and recreate?

Answer (score 0):

You have composite-partitioned table, so this is normal situation.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E3F353CB-9748-44D4-B7B1-4BBAAF618D9D.htm

In your case on table or partition level you can modify default attributes.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-C003E6DB-3867-4407-86D2-A51F30AF07CC.htm#VLDBG1177